# Использование интерфейсов

Tags: java

Есть классы: Животное, Кот и Собака с интерфейсом дрессируемый.

```
public class Animal
public class Cat extends Animal
public class Dog extends Animal implements Training
public interface Training { void jump(); }
```

Нужно написать функцию, которая получает животное, проверяет дрессируемое ли оно и если да, то выполняет команду. Что-то вроде:

```
public void Test(Animal animal) {
    if(animal instanceof Training) { animal.jump(); }
}
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти правильно, только `{ animal.jump(); }` компилятор не пропустит, потому что animal имеет тип Animal, у которого нет метода jump(). В Java наличие полей и методов проверяется по типу ссылки, а не объекта, на который она указывает. Поэтому нужно выполнить приведение ссылки к типу Training одним из двух нижеследующих способов:

`((Training)animal).jump();`

```
Training trainingAnimal = (Training)animal;
trainingAnimal.jump();
```

Answer (score 3):

Так у вас уже почти нормально написано, надо только `animal.jump()` заменить на `((Training) animal).jump()`. Т.к. в `Animal` нет `jump`, то мы его кастуем к Training